# Is it possible to access COM objects from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, com

I have a desktop application for which I wanna create a chrome extension. I just need to know if I can access windows COM objects from a chrome extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot (directly).

If you need that, you'll need to create some native application "proxy" that will talk to your extension over [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) protocol, and talk to your existing application via whatever native method you want (e.g. COM).

Note that this Native Host application cannot be bundled with the extension in Web Store; but you could bundle it with your desktop application.